# Is the soft margin primal problem convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning

The soft margin SVM optimisation problem is defined as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimise}_{\xi, w, b}& \frac{1}{2}||w||^2 + C\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i \\
\text{s.t}\;\;&y^{(i)}(w^Tx^{(i)} + b) \geq 1-\xi_i,\;\;i =1,...n \\
&\xi_i \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$

I know that $\frac{1}{2}||w||^2$ is a convex problem. Are the objective and the constraint functions convex as well? I know that additions of two convex functions $f(x) + g(x)$ is a convex function. However, the objective function involves the addition of multiple variable function $w$ and $\xi$. Will they still be convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is convex.

Each of the constraint corresponds to a half-space.  The feasible set is a polyhedral.

Comment: is it always the case that the sum of two convex functions is convex even though their variables might be different?

Comment: sum of convex function is always convex. You can view them as having the same variables so that things are well-defined. for example $f(x,y)=x$, $g(x,y)=y$. $f(x,y)+g(x,y)=x+y$ is convex.